# How do I keep an image saved on an application even after the app closes?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making a card holder app, the user is supposed to take a picture of his id, contacts, notes etc. so he can later use them digitally. Problem is how do I take a camera input and save it as an image *inside* the application so it stays there?

Comment: Write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the native Camera Application of your device to get the image and then save it to the device . Android Team has done much easy for developers to perform such task.

You need to make use of ActivityContracts and MediaStore to take the image and store it into your device respectively.

Step 1 :
First Generate a Uri for your Image , in the following manner

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    suspend fun createPhotoUri(source: Source): Uri? {
        val imageCollection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } else {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        }
        val dirDest = File(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
            context.getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator + "CAMERA"
        )
        val date = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val fileName = "$date.jpg"


        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val newImage = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirDest${File.separator}")

            }

            return@withContext context.contentResolver.insert(imageCollection, newImage)
        }
    }
```

Step 2:
Then when you want to capture the Image , then on the OnClickListener perform the following :

```
binding.takePictureButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {

                    viewModel.createPhotoUri(Source.CAMERA)?.let { uri ->
                        actionTakePicture.launch(uri)
                    }
               
            }
        }
```

Step 3 :
The actionTakePicture ActivityContract is as follows :

```
private val actionTakePicture = registerForActivityResult(TakePicture()) { success ->
        if (!success) {
            Log.d(tag, "Image taken FAIL")
            return@registerForActivityResult
        }

        Log.d(tag, "Image taken SUCCESS")

       
    }
```

And you are done with capturing you Image and storing it .

**Make sure you declare permission's before using the above code  ,else it wont work .**

The answer mentioned by @StefanoSansone can also be used . But the issue with that is you need to perfectly setup CameraX library and that might be tedious for your useCase . One should use library like CameraX if they want to have more control on Camera with other camera capabilities , when you application is more of a Camera Application . Else using the above method is perfectly fine . Saves one from tedious work .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin and Jetpack libraries, I suggest you to take a look to [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) library.

You can use the [`takePicture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)) method to take a photo with camera and save it in the storage.

A complete example can be found in the [CameraX codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started)

```kotlin
private fun takePhoto() {
   // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
   val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

   // Create time-stamped output file to hold the image
   val photoFile = File(
       outputDirectory,
       SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US
       ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

   // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
   val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

   // Set up image capture listener, which is triggered after photo has
   // been taken
   imageCapture.takePicture(
       outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
           override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
           }

           override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
               val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
               val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
               Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               Log.d(TAG, msg)
           }
       })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulties last week with saving images.
I finally used sharedPreferences files and saved bitmap as text.
From what I've heard it's not a good practice, It's better to save in files and save the path.
However the code is very compact and it's working really well (in my case never have to load more than 4 pictures)

```
                var bm= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri)
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)  //bm is the bitmap object
                val b = baos.toByteArray()
                val encoded: String = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
                editor.putString("backgroundBitmap",encoded)//put the bitmap as text in sharedPref files, use to back the bitmap in mainActivity
                editor.commit()
```